# paramiko sftp script works on test server not on production

Tags: python

I'm a newb at python, so please excuse the hack job I created in order to transfer the contents of a folder into an ssh server.

The problem is that it works great in my test server, but as soon as run it against  the actual server that I need to upload files for I receive the error below, and I'm not sure what it means.
I've googled it, but I can't figure it out, please help.
Thanks.

```
import paramiko
import glob
import os
from shutil import move

host = "192.168.1.87"                    #hard-coded
port = 22
password ="passwd"            #hard-coded
username = "administator"     #hard-coded

remotepath =''  #hard-coded
localpath =   'D:\\PH/PH_PROD\\PowerConnectInterf1_WINS\\bin\\data\\Sheex\\bc\\945\\'

#build filename array
os.chdir("D:/PH/PH_PROD/PowerConnectInterf1_WINS/bin/data/Sheex/bc/945")
filelist=[]

for files in glob.glob( "2016*" ):
    f = open(files, 'r')
    filelist.append(f.name)

f.close()

if (len(filelist)>0):
    transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
    transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

    for s in filelist:
        #print remotepath+s
        sftp.put(localpath+s,remotepath+s)
        #os.rename(localpath+s,localpath+"945back/"+s)
sftp.close()
transport.close()
#print 'Upload done.'
```

Error:

```
D:\Scripts>python mysftp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysftp.py", line 37, in <module>
    sftp.put(localpath+s,remotepath+s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 676, in put

    return self.putfo(fl, remotepath, file_size, callback, confirm)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 634, in put
fo
    with self.file(remotepath, 'wb') as fr:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 327, in ope
n
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 730, in _re
quest
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 781, in _re
ad_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 807, in _co
nvert_status
    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text)
IOError: [Errno 2] Invalid file ID
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the path you are writing on the server doesn't exist. You should check and create if doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi, I am writing to the root path when I log in, so not sure if that is the issue.

Comment: I've tried adjusting the target pat to //, /existingfolder, etc.. but still getting the same answer, I also set  sftp.put(localpath+s,s) instead of sftp.put(localpath+s,remotepath+s)